# Cycling on NSTableView rows

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I have NSTableview with N rows and two columns (column_A and column_B).
I want cycling on rows, i try so :

```
IBOutlet id myTableView;

NSTableColumn *column_A = [myTableView tableColumnWithIdentifier:@"A"];
NSTableColumn *column_B = [myTableView tableColumnWithIdentifier:@"B"];
int nr = [myTableView numberOfRows];
for (int i = 0; i<nr; i++) {
    NSString *a = [[column_A dataCellForRow:i] stringValue];
    NSString *b = [[column_B dataCellForRow:i] stringValue];
    ... (other code)
    a = nil;
    b = nil;
}
```

But I get same values,

for i = 0 I get a = test1 and b= test2

for i = 1 I get a = test1 and b= test2

...

for i = nr -1 I get a = test1 and b = test2

Where is the error ?

Answer (score 0):

`-[NSTableColumn dataCellForRow:]` returns the *prototype* cell that is used to show the value at that column and row. This prototype cell can be reused for multiple rows in the same column, so you cannot rely on it having the specific value shown at a given row.

In general, if you want to enumerate the values shown by a table view, you iterate over its data source—an `NSTableViewDataSource`-conforming instance, which can be obtained via `-[NSTableView dataSource]`, or an `NSArrayController` instance bound to `contents` if you are using bindings.

If for some reason you cannot or do not want to use the data source, you should use `-[NSTableView preparedCellAtColumn:row:]` instead. This method makes sure that the cell is populated with the data source/content value for a given column and row.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I will try preparedCellAtColumn method today and then I will say you.

Comment: @user2724095 Why can’t you use the data source?

Comment: All ok, thank you very much . With preparedCellAtColumn method is ok. Then I try with dataSource too. Thank you very much